# cdk virtual scrolling with sticky header html table angular

Tags: html, css, angular6, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I am getting more than 30000 records from backend to list in frontend, So using cdk-virtual-scroll I can able to achieve this. I have created normal table enclosed with cdk-tag

```
          <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport [itemSize] = "20">
            <div class="result_table">
             <table class="dataframe" border="1">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th >
                  Name
                </th>
                <th >
                  Description
                </th>
                <th >
                  Group
                </th>
                <th >
                  Data
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr *cdkVirtualFor ="let data of address_obj_data_holder | filter:searchAddr">
                    <td >
                      {{data.name}}
                    </td>
                                             
                    <td >
                      {{data.description}}
                    </td>
                    <td >
                     {{data.group}}
                    </td> 
                    <td >
                     {{data.data}}
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

If I do like this, table header also scrolls when I scrolls down, and If I do like,

```
          <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport [itemSize] = "20">
            <div class="result_table">
             <table class="dataframe" border="1">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th style="width: 20% !important;">
                  Name
                </th>
                <th style="width: 40% !important;">
                  Description
                </th>
                <th style="width: 20% !important;">
                  Group
                </th>
                <th style="width: 20% !important;">
                  Data
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr *cdkVirtualFor ="let data of address_obj_data_holder | filter:searchAddr">
                    <td style="width: 20% !important;">
                      {{data.name}}
                    </td>
                                             
                    <td style="width: 40% !important;">
                      {{data.description}}
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 20% !important;">
                    {{data.group}}
                    </td> 
                    <td style="width: 20% !important;">
                      {{data.data}}
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

width of header and tbody is slightly different both are not in same width as we have scroll in below body alone. Can some one help me to fix this alignment issue.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Each header position could be adjusted with the method

```
 <th [style.top]="inverseOfTranslation"> ... </th>
```

And related code

```
 @ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport, { static: false })
  public viewPort: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;

public get inverseOfTranslation(): string {
    if (!this.viewPort) {
      return '-0px';
    }
    const offset = this.viewPort.getOffsetToRenderedContentStart();

    return `-${offset}px`;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`<th [style.top]="inverseOfTranslation()" style="width:50px;">LOT No.

```js
@ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport) viewport!: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;
    inverseOfTranslation(): string {
        if (!this.viewport) {
          return '-0px';
        }
        const offset = this.viewport.getOffsetToRenderedContentStart();
    
        return `-${offset}px`;
      }
```

```css
thead tr:first-child th { position: sticky; top: 0; background-color: inherit; }
```

```html
<th [style.top]="inverseOfTranslation()" style="width:50px;">LOT No.</th>
```

`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

If you are looking to make the header sticky of table and you are using cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport, then try this:

```
table { overflow: auto; }
thead { position: sticky; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you have more than 20 items. Because the whole container translates on the Y axis.